# Excel VBA - SQL Error: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level %s

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to connect a database but I am getting error "SQL Error: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level %s" at line- **conn.open** my code was working till yesterday but from today morning I am facing this issue.

this is the code I wrote:

```
Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
Conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDAORA; Password= " & Password & ";User ID= " & userId & "; Data Source = " & Ambiente & ";Persist Security Info=True"
conn.open
```

***Thanks in advance***

Comment: Is that your exact code, or did you type in that last line?  Last instance of conn is not capitalized, which might indicate an issue...

Comment: Does your database have a logon trigger?
 https://forums.asp.net/t/1318277.aspx?Problem+with+oracle+connections+ORA+604+error+occurred+at+recursive+SQL+level+s

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following:

- Write `debug.print Conn.ConnectionString` before `conn.Open`.
- Take the information from the immediate window and try to log in
  manually to the DB with it.
- I am pretty sure that you can debug further, depending on the
  result.

Or try like this:

```
Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.open "Provider=MSDAORA; Password= " & _
             Password & ";User ID= " & userId & "; Data Source = " & Ambiente & "
```

Comment: I am able to log-in using information from the immediate window

Comment: That's strange, @Srijan. Can you write then `Conn.Open Conn.ConnectionString` instead of `conn.open` and try again?

Comment: @Srijan - did you try the 2. solution from my answer?